# Alternar funções javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

No meu código há um botão, que, quando clicado, toca uma música

```
<div class="botao" id="btn1"><audio id="audio1" controls loop="true" style=" visibility: hidden;">
  <source src="musica/song.wav" type="audio/wav">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio></div>
```

Mas, como eu faço para, depois que já começou a tocar, ele parar uma música e vice-versa, em JS? Eu tentei o seguinte:

```
var sng1 = document.getElementById("audio1"); 
var bt1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
btn1.onclick = onclick = function(event){
   sng1.play();
```

Mas não sei o que fazer para parar a música. Desde já, obrigado. :D

Comment: Olá Jvsierra, seja bem vindo ao SOpt, editei sua pergunta pra adequá-la ao site. Utilize o snippet apenas quando se tratar de um exemplo completo e verificável, caso contrário utilize apenas "amostra de código" (o `{}` do editor).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O objeto também tem um método `pause`, e uma propriedade `paused` para verificar se já está pausado. Então você pode fazer assim:

```
var sng1 = document.getElementById("audio1"); 
var bt1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
btn1.onclick = function(event){
    if(sng1.paused) {    
       sng1.play();
    } else {
       sng1.pause();
    }
}
```

<sup>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6vm2vbbh/)</sup>